# Do US long distance buses enforce their luggage rules?

Tags: usa, luggage, buses, regulations, long-haul

I bought a Megabus ticket.  On the ticket, it says:

> You may bring 1 (one) standard sized suitcase (weighing no more than 50 pounds) per reservation and 1 carry on-piece which is capable of being stored beneath the seat in front of you. Luggage in excess of this allowance is likely to be refused.

I have more luggage.  Is this rule typically enforced?

Answer (score 6):

I found a story going back to 2010 about [Megabus being taken out of service](http://www.subchat.com/buschat/readflat.asp?Id=190310) for being overweight.  Now while buses are normally not subject to routine weight inspections you might consider the bus being used on the route.  Megabus uses double deckers like [Van Hool Astromega](http://www.vanhool.be/ENG/coaches/Coaches-USA/td925astromegausaEN.html) have limited space for luggage so it is likely to be enforced pretty strictly.

There is a blog entry on [You've been reviewed](http://www.youvebeenreviewed.net/2012/12/megabus-tightens-luggage-restrictions.html) that deals with personal experience of someone who had taken Megabus after the rules went into effect.

Answer (score 5):

They have started enforcing this rule strictly especially in more popular routes. I cannot speak for the routes when the passengers are few. In my personal experience, if you have excess baggage, you can always pay for an extra ticket to the Megabus official there and they would allow your excess baggage on board, so you shouldn't have a problem.

Caveat: If the bus is full, I'm unsure if you will be given the option to purchase another ticket for your luggage.

Answer (score 1):

I traveled a lot 2014-2018.  At some Greyhound stations, **every** bag was weighed.  At others, no attention was paid to it at all.